# UI diagram layout

Tags: java, diagramming

Wanted to generate a UI diagram (with nice layout) depicting relationships amongst network components. Which is the best Java based API to do such layouts with minimum fuss and light codebase.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're looking for.  Do you want to generate diagrams from existing source, do you want a GUI to diagram relationships as part of your design process, or do you want to programmatically generate diagrams using a Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're logging for a Java API that can do layouts (e.g. arrange boxes in a hierarchical fashion without overlap), check out [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/).

Answer (score 2):

yWorks.  http://www.yworks.com/en/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Any uml tool should do the work

Take a look at [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) or [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) as UML editors made in Java.

(BTW, Visio Is usually the standard tool for that job)